# How to adjust the Tab widget

Tags: android, android-tabhost

```
  I am developing an application in android for which i have to use nine tabs in the main layout.
```

But all tabs in one view doesn't look nice.So i decided to show five tabs in one view and other four on click of one of the tabs.But it is not working when i click the fifth tab to show the other four tabs can you suggest me to set all tabs in my application in a better gui.

Thanx in Advance